# Generate tag cloud:object doesn't support this property

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-cloud

I am trying to create a tag cloud using the jquery plugins
[here](https://github.com/mikeal/testbot/tree/master/testbot/static/tagcloud/scripts)

and using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
  generateTagCloud();

});

function generateTagCloud()
{

     $("#xlist").tagcloud();
}

 </script>
<div><!--JQueryTagCloud-->
<ul id="xlist" class="xmpl">
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/design">design</a> </li>
 <li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/blog">blog</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/programming">programming</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/tools">tools</a> </li>
 <li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/music">music</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/software">software</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/webdesign">webdesign</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/web2.0">web2.0</a> </li>
 <li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/video">video</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/art">art</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://del.icio.us/tag/reference">reference</a> </li>
</ul>
```

But i get the following error:
    `Object doesn't support this property or method`.All the scripts are being loaded. I am not able to figure out why am i getting this error.

Please help me!!

Comment: Did you included jquery.tagcloud.js file in your coding ?

Comment: yes i have included. and it is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the same in my local instance, You need to include follwing files into your code for your example.,

Source: https://github.com/mikeal/testbot/tree/master/testbot/static/tagcloud/scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tagcloud.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tinysort.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: maybe this is incorrect char case in `tagcloud();`

```
$("#xlist").tagcloud();
$("#xlist").tagCloud(); //correct case
```

or use

```
$(function(){
   generateTagCloud();
});
```

instead of `$(document).ready` I guess there can be no `ready` function

Comment: can you post what `console.log($("#xlist").tagcloud);`  and `console.log($(document).ready);` display in JS console